# navigation.xml not showing design tab

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: nav]

I opened a open-source apk file by flie/profile or debug apk
My android studio shows only texts.

What should I do to make it look like this?

[image]

Comment: If you wish to open it in the design mode: Press the resource manager (can be found on the bar on the left of your first screenshot), press "Navigation", and select "Design"

Comment: I managed to open Resources Manager/Navigation, but it says "No navigation available" @NotVeryCreative

Comment: It might be related to the error (visible on the first screenshot you posted), could you hover over that and show the error message?

Comment: It says "URI is not registerd (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and TDTs):3" @JustSightseeng

Comment: To be honest this isn't a very helpful error code (not your fault), simply it might have many causes, try to use "FIle | Invalidate Caches..." setting